# Update pivot column values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, pivot

For the sake of argument although the relation is one2many (*a tree has birds*) lets examine imaginary many2many example to describe the problem.

I have a pivot table representing birds perched on a tree 
and each bird has index representing the order of birds on a tree which means unique trio `$table->unique( array('index', 'tree_id', 'bird_id') )`.

```
tree_id | bird_id | index
-------- --------- -------
  ...       ...      ...
   1         3        1 
  ...       ...      ...
```

So when a new bird lands on a tree I want it to become the first bird on the tree and to increment the indexes of rest on the tree.

What's the way of doing that efficiently using eloquent?

Answer (score 2):

According to my understanding, you have a relationship of **Many to Many** between Tree and Bird Model, so your tables should look like this:

```
- trees
    - id
    - name
    ...

- birds
    - id
    - name
    - ...

- bird_tree
    - id
    - bird_id
    - tree_id
    - index
```

And your Models should look like this:

```
class Tree extends Model
{

    public function birds()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Bird::class)
                    ->withPivot('index')
                    ->withTimestamps();
    }

}

class Bird extends Model
{

    public function trees()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tree::class)
                    ->withPivot('index')
                    ->withTimestamps();
    }

}
```

Whereas if you want to add a new entry into the pivot table `bird_tree`, you can use `attach()` method like this:

```
$tree->birds()->attach(1, ['index' => 1]);
                       ^
     bird's id_________|
```

and if you want to update any row, jus for example if you want to update any index for any entry in the *`bird_tree`* table you can use `updateExistingPivot()` method for this:

```
$tree->birds()->sync([$bird->id => [ 'index' => 'someValue'] ]);
```

> See Laravel Docs for:
>
> - [Many to Many Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)
> - [attach()](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_attach)
> - [updateExistingPivot()](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_updateExistingPivot)

Hope this helps!

Comment: 10x sorry about the delay I will approve an answer as soon as I test solutions +1

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
// Tree.php

public function perchBird($birdId)
{
    $perched = $this->birds->pluck('id')->toArray();
    $perched = array_combine($perched, array_fill(0, count($perched), ['index' => DB::raw('`index`+1')]));
    $perched[$birdId] = ['index' => 1];

    $this->birds()->sync($perched);
}
```

Breaking it down:

1) Fetch already perched birds' ids

```
$perched = $this->birds->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

2) Create an associative array with perched birds' ids as keys and the update statement as values, using `DB::raw` so that Laravel understands it is a MySQL calculation and not a value in itself. That way we can take the existing index and increment it.

```
$perched = array_combine($perched, array_fill(0, count($perched), ['index' => DB::raw('`index`+1')]));
```

3) Add the newly perched bird to the array, with the index of 1.

```
$perched[$birdId] = ['index' => 1];
```

4) Trigger the pivot table sync

```
$this->birds()->sync($perched);
```

It's worth noting that the `sync` method will run each update statement individually, which can be prohibitive depending on the numbers of perched birds you expect to have, or in the frequency with which they will be updated. The alternative would be to do a single raw query for incrementing the indexes, then another for perching a new bird:

```
public function perchBird($birdId)
{
    DB::update('update bird_tree set `index` = (`index`+1) where tree_id = ?', [$this->id]);
    $this->birds()->attach($birdId, ['index' => 1]);
}
```

Not exactly Eloquent, as requested, but still quite simple and readable.

Comment: 10x sorry about the delay I will approve an answer as soon as I test solutions +1